# Clickable particles in three.js PointCloud

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I am visualizing 3d data points (which I read in via a csv-file) with the help of three.js. 
I want to click on points in that PointCloud to show other measurement data for those specific points. 
According to examples I found this is possible apparently but I don't get it working. 
I have the following code (basically from those examples):

```
function onDocumentMouseMove(e) {       
    mouseVector.x = 2 * (e.clientX / containerWidth) - 1;
    mouseVector.y = 1 - 2 * (e.clientY / containerHeight);
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouseVector.x, mouseVector.y, 0.5).unproject(camera);
    raycaster.ray.set(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());
    scene.updateMatrixWorld();
    intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(particles);
    console.log(intersects);
}
```

But intersects always is an empty array no matter which point I move over.

Regarding the particles Object I wrote the following:

```
geometry = new THREE.Geometry();        

for (var i = 0; i < howmany; i++) {
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(data[i][0], data[i][2], data[i][1] );
    geometry.vertices.push(vector);
}

attributes = {
     size: { type: 'f', value: [] },
     customColor: { type: 'c', value: [] }
};

uniforms = {
    color: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0xFFFFFF ) },
    texture: { type: "t", value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "js/threejs/examples/textures/sprites/disc.png" ) }
};

var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    uniforms: uniforms,
    attributes: attributes,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexshader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentshader' ).textContent,
    alphaTest: 0.9,
} );

particles = new THREE.PointCloud( geometry, shaderMaterial );

for (var i = 0; i < howmany; i++) {
    colors[i] = new THREE.Color(RainBowColor(data[i][3], 4));
    sizes[i] = PARTICLE_SIZE * 0.5;
}
scene.add(particles);
```

where all the the variables are initialized previously, PARTICLE_SIZE is 20 and particles are about 10.000 in number with values between (0,0,0) and (10000,10000,10000). For rotating and zooming I use THREE.OrbitControls.

Does anyone see the mistake or is raycasting with particles not possible in this case?

Many thanks,
Mika.

Comment: `THREE.Raycaster.params.PointCloud.threshold` is 1 by default. Try increasing it. Step through with the debugger on a small problem having 2 particles.

Comment: I just spontaneously tried `raycaster.params.PointCloud.threshold = 20;` and ... it worked. I will have to work on the fine tuning of point sizes anyways. So, at first, it helps a lot that i know the importance of that threshold. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using `Raycaster` with `Points` (formerly `PointCloud`), you need to be aware that in the `Raycaster` constructor,

```
params.Points.threshold = 1
```

You may have to change that value, depending on the scale of your scene. The units of `threshold` are in world units.

Also, the click area will only be approximate, because the code does not take into consideration any transparency in `Points.material.map`.

three.js r.72

Comment: I have not defined "Raycaster.params" in "THREE" object. Any changes in R71?

ERR.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PointCloud' of undefined

Comment: @raphaelRauwolf  PointCloud -> Points. Thanks for the tip.